# KenLM perplexity weirdness

Tags: nlp, language-model

I have 96 files each containing ~10K lines of English text (tokenized, downcased).  If I loop through the files (essentially doing k-fold cross-validation with k=#files) and build a LM (using bin/lmplz) for 95 and run bin/query on the held out file against it, I see a PPL (including OOVs) of 1.0 every time.  But if I run a file against an LM built with all 96 files (so test doc is included in building the LM), I get a PPL of 27.8.

I have more experience with SRILM than KenLM, but I've never seen a perplexity score of 1.  Something feels wrong about that.  Even if I accepted that and attributed it to the test document's sentences occurring in other training data, it wouldn't explain why when I ensure that the test data is included in the training data I get a higher score.  What's going on?

=============================

this also seems strange:

```
Perplexity including OOVs:  1
Perplexity excluding OOVs:  0.795685
OOVs:   0
```

Comment: After feedback from Kenneth Heafield himself, I did a lot more experiments.  I can't figure out exactly why yet, but something in the way the data was prepared was causing this behavior.  After some modifications to my pre-processing steps, I'm seeing much more reasonable results.  I don't feel like "because your data looks funny" is a good enough answer, though, so I'm leaving the question open.